# AutoMapper - Map source object as property in the destination object

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, automapper

I have these two class
`

```
//source 
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Phonee{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    public UserEducation userEducation { get; set; }
}

// destination 
public class UserEducation
{
    [Key]
    public int UserEducationId { get; set; }
    public string University { get; set; }
    public int  YearOfGraduation { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is try to map the source object to destination object as one of its properties

`userEducation = _mapper.Map<UserEducation>(User);`
  `CreateMap<User.UserEduation>().FromMember(dir => dir.User, ???);`

Comment: @Hubssein Shukri, could you click 'accept this answer'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this example. It can map `User` to `UserEducation` well.

```
public class CustomMapper : Profile
{
    public CustomMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserEducation>()
            .ForMember(dir => dir.User, x=>x.MapFrom(t=> new User
            {
                UserId=t.UserId,
                Name=t.Name,
                Email=t.Email,
                Phonee=t.Phonee 
            }));
    }
}
```